# git pull asks for password everytime

Tags: git, ssh

that question has already ask a million times and non of the solutions seems to work for me. I run openSuse Linux and everytime I do a git pull (or push) I get

```
git-files> git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/home/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

When running ssh-add or ssh-add -k the password is only stored until the next restart.

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Although this looks like a Git question, it's really an ssh question.

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu Quick Tips](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/QuickTips#Tip_.233_Keychain_-_Manage_ssh_keys) suggests to use the keychain to persists your SSH keys passphrases.

[Adapted to OpenSuse](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?package=keychain&project=security):

```sh
# For openSUSE Tumbleweed run the following as root:

zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/security.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install keychain

# add the following lines to your ${HOME}/.bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc:

keychain id_rsa id_dsa
source ~/.keychain/$(uname -n)-sh
```

---

The alternative would be to switch to an HTTPS URL, which requires a username/password (or token), and use a [git credential storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage).
But this has nothing to do with SSH anymore.

Comment: when I enter this code to my bashrc then after logon the system doesn't continue to boot into KDE, I assume it tries to get the interactive password input this requires.

Comment: @yup try the source command directly from the command line, and enter the credentials there. Then, check if the logon succeeds.